# Could I replace URLRewriteFilter with Rewrite?

Tags: java, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

One of my projects use [URLRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). URLRewriteFilter has a rewrite xml file. The [Rewrite](http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/) gives me programatic configuration. In my opnion it's a more elegant way to configure and I wish use them.

My problem is that they do not have enough documentation or a javadoc page.

For now I need LINKs as good as possible of documentation and know if it is possible use programatic configuration.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: DiogoSantana, actually I already found my answer. Thank you your interest.

Comment: Please, post it here. It may be usefull for someone else. You can post a answer to your own question.